# Create pipeline that consists of multiple pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is there a possibility to create a release pipeline, that consists of other pipelines?

**Assets**

In my case I have following pipelines:
- build job Job1 (to build some application artifacts)
- build job Job2 (to build some application artifacts)
- build job Job3 (to build other artifacts, e.g. tests)
- release job Release1 (to deploy application form artifacts from Job1 and Job2)
- release job Release2 (to prepare special DB for tests)
- release job Release3 (to run tests from Job3)

Each of above build consists of many tasks and task groups.

**Goal**

Is to prepare following pipeline, that will be scheduled every night (so just a regular nightly build-release):

`[trigger: at specific time] -> (Job1, Job2, Job3) -> Release2 -> Release1 -> Release3`

**Restrictions**

I can not merge any of mentioned jobs/releases, because we need to run some of them independently.

**Ideas**

One thing I conciser was to make task groups out of all jobs and releases (that already consists of task groups...) and to prepare new release pipeline, but this idea sounds like not-the-best option.

Comment: You could trigger your build pipelines with a PowerShell Skript inside your release pipeline with a REST API POST `${ServerUrl}/${xCollection}/${xProject}/_apis/build/builds?ignoreWarnings=false&api-version=5.0-preview.4`. You also need a `authorization header` and a `json body` to send this post command.

Comment: Hi, how the things going? Does the below answer could help you achieve your expected? If yes, you can accept the answer thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works. If you still facing some issues, feel free to leave comment here :-)

Comment: Hello, sorry for late response! For now we made task groups out of pipelines - it felt a little easier to do. About API - I had no time to check that solution (yet!).

Comment: @Drop, glad you have got a easier solution about your question. You can share your answer and accept it. It will help other community users who have the sam error. You can refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58862131/checkout-git-submodule-in-azure-pipeline-with-ssh) about how to accept the answer. Thanks. : )

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to accomplish this via the [Trigger Build Task Azure DevOps extension.](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks) However, you should note the warning under the "Known Issues" section regarding using this extension with Release pipelines. Under this approach you'd create a single "mega" pipeline comprised of various calls to the extension which would trigger your existing build and release pipelines.

In my view, a better approach would be to adopt the use of [YAML templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates) to create [YAML based pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema). You could create a template for each stage you've outlined in your question and then simply reference the template in your pipelines. This way you could have your standalone pipelines and your "mega" pipelines referencing the same templates to promote re-use and improve maintainability. There is even an easy way to [export your current "classic" pipelines to YAML.](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/909#issuecomment-393619028)