# Checkout git submodule in Azure Pipeline with SSH

Tags: ssh, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, git-submodules

I try to checkout the git submodules via ssh instead of https (default if you use "Checkout submodules") in an Azure DevOps Pipeline. With the option in the picture it works - but for the developers it's annoying to enter the password all the time if they are working with the repository.

[image]

For that I used the following instructions to add the [ssh key.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/ssh?view=azure-devops)
I created a public and a private key, and copied the known_host entry.

That's my YAML file snippet:

```
stages:
- stage: DeployBackend
jobs:
  - job: SSH
    steps:
      - task: InstallSSHKey@0
        inputs:
          knownHostsEntry: $(known_host)
          sshPublicKey: $(public_key)
          sshKeySecureFile: 'private_key_file'
  - job: Deploy
    steps:
      - checkout: self
        submodules: true
      - script: |
          -- here I run all docker commands to build the container and push it to Azure --
        displayName: "Deploy"
```

If I use the SSH keys to clone the repository to my local computer I have no issues. But if I run the pipeline it will crash at the submodule checkout:

> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists. fatal: clone of
>   'git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/***repoLink***'
>   into submodule path '/home/vsts/work/1/s/app/submoduleFolder' failed
>   Failed to clone 'app/submoduleFolder'. Retry scheduled Cloning into
>   '/home/vsts/work/1/s/app/submoduleFolder'... Host key verification
>   failed. fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

That's the `.gitmodules` file in the repo - it works without any issues locally:

```
[submodule "app/subModuleName"]
    path = app/subModuleName
    url = git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/***/subModuleName
    branch = master
```

I even wrote the `id_rsa`, `known_hosts` and `id_rsa.pub` files into `.ssh` with a script, but it seems like they are not even used for ssh verification.

Comment: Glad you have the solution. You can convert it to answer and accept it. It will help other community users who have the same error. You can refer to [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) about how to accept the answer. Thanks. : )

Comment: Please place answers in Answer blocks. Later, you can accept your own Answer. Also see [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/173448)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to do all the tasks in one job. Variables are not shared between different `job` instances.

This works:

```
jobs:
    - job: jobName
      steps:
        - task: AzureKeyVault@1
          inputs:
            azureSubscription: '***'
            KeyVaultName: '***'
          displayName: "Read Secrets from KeyVault"
        - task: InstallSSHKey@0
          inputs:
            knownHostsEntry: $(known_host)
            sshPublicKey: $(public_key)
            sshKeySecureFile: 'private_key_file'
          displayName: "Create SSH files"
        - script: |
            git clone --recurse-submodules git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/****
            git submodule update --init --recursive
            docker login -u $(userName) -p $(password) ***
            docker build ****
            docker push ****
          displayName: "Build and Push Docker Container"
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to edit the `.gitmodules` path to be a relative url, eg `url = ../subModuleName`:

```
[submodule "app/subModuleName"]
    path = app/subModuleName
    url = ../subModuleName
    branch = master
```

The url is now relative to the parent repo's url. So when the ado pipeline clones it via https, it uses the same for the submodule. Developers can clone the repo using either https or ssh, and the submodule will use the same - no need to enter passwords.