# Push git current branch to a remote git in Azure Pipeline

Tags: git, azure-pipelines

Using old fashion way in Azure Dev Ops to create pipeline, I'm looking for a solution to push the git current branch to a remote git. This is really not conventional I know, but if it's done automatically, I have to do it manually and I'm not good to remember things. Moreover, I like to resolve new challenge.

Here is what I have currently:
[image]

And the script executed is:

```
git remote add EXT git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/EXT/EXT-Project/ext-web-app
git fetch
git push origin HEAD:master --force
git branch -f develop origin/develop
git pull EXT develop
```

What I noticed is when the Command Line task starts:

- the git is currently on a detached branch
- so I force to go to the local develop branch (the branch I want to copy to EXT remot git)
- then I try to pull the current branch (develop) to the external Git

Question:

- How to set up the credentials of the external git (EXT)?
- How to finish the script to synch the current git branch to the external git branch?

Note: I don't need to handle the merge conflict with the external git branch, if it happens, the pipeline failed and that's it (it's not supposed to happen btw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Install SSH Key task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/install-ssh-key?view=azure-devops), as seen in "[Checkout git submodule in Azure Pipeline with SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58876552/6309)", in order to force the pipeline to use your private/public key.

Make sure you have the right to access the `EXT/EXT-Project`, meaning the public key which will authenticate you must refer to an account authorized to read `EXT/EXT-Project`.